# Make GCC Use iret instead of ret

Tags: gcc, nasm, interrupt-handling

I am trying to use interrupts in my simple operating system. I have successfully set up the IDT, and have made a C function in assembly to set a gate (below), but now I have a problem: How would I write an interrupt handler, ending with `iret`, in C?
Here is my code:

```
setGate: ;the first argument is the gate number
         ;the second the address to the function
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
push eax
push ebx

mov  eax, [ebp+12]
mov  ebx, idtStart
add  ebx, [ebp+8]
mov  [ebx*8], ax
mov  word [ebx*8+2], 0x8
mov  word [ebx*8+4], 0x8E00
shr  eax, 16
mov  [ebx*8+6], ax

pop  ebx
pop  eax
pop  ebp
ret
```

My C code is:

```
void handler(void)
{
    print("The interrupt has been handled", 15, 0);
}

void main(void)
{
    loadIDT();
    setGate(32, (unsigned long)&handler);
    __asm__("int $32");
}
```

This code causes the OS to crash, however when I use assembly and `iret` it doesn't.

I am compiling with GCC and Nasm, and emulating on Qemu, in 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: So add `__asm__("iret")`, what's the problem?

Comment: @n.m. For some reason, it still doesn't work. It looks as if QEMU is constantly reloading.

Comment: If you use GCC 7.0+ there is a newly supported (on x86) attribute [`__attribute__((interrupt))__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) feature that will generate the `iret`.

Comment: @n.m. : Bad idea given that GCC may have function prologue and epilogue that may unbalance the stack. That method would only be recommended if GCC also supported the naked function attribute on x86 but it doesn't. Tying yourself to how a compiler may generate code (for example your method might work if the frame pointer is omitted, but not guaranteed). i consider it a poor choice as it may cause serious breakage if the compiler changes or someone iuses different compiler options.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Your solution worked, thanks! Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I used `__attribute__((interrupt))`

Comment: @SabrinaJewson would you post as an accepted answer your solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch),[`__attribute__((interrupt))__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) on my interrupt handler/function worked for my situation.

Unfortunately, as this was five years ago I can’t give any more details on what I did. At the time I was very satisfied with the solution.